# Debug which function was fired using Firebug

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, firebug

I am trying to debug someone else's UI implementation, and it is really hard at this point to know what events are calling which `functions`.

Is there a way to know what `function` was called when I trigger an event? Maybe with `Firebug`?

Comment: Are the events attached to inspectable DOM elements?

Comment: That is what I can't figure out.

Comment: How do you trigger the events? By clicking things, moving the mouse, etc?

Comment: It is a click event, but I can't find a reference to what that is bound to.

Comment: In that case it's probably bound to `window` or `document` (assuming it happens when you click anywhere). I was going to suggest selecting the element and looking in the "Event Listeners" panel, but I guess that won't help.

Comment: Check this out! It might be useful
http://haineault.com/blog/74/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In chrome developer toolbar you can set event breakpoints. - hope this will help

[image]

Comment: Ok, this is great. Is there a way to skip to the next breakpoint?

Comment: yes sure. You can step over(F10) || step into (F11) functions. Chrome debugger is a pretty awesome tool to debug scripts. You can catch event directly from DOM nodes (Click on Elements tab > right click on element > select "break on sub tree modifications").

Answer (score 4):

There's an extension to Firebug called EventBug. There are actually quite a few extensions to Firebug that are awesome.

http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#Eventbug

[image: EventBug screenshot]

EventBug lets you see the event functions that are attached to an element and set breakpoints in their handlers.

Answer (score 1):

You may also try to use Firebug's "Break on next" feature when in Script Tab. After enabling it, it will break whenever some script is going to be executed.

[image: Break on next]

This however has a disadvantage that if you use a framework that is listening to mouse events globally (e.g. bound to `<body>`), you will get a break point whenever you move your mouse, so then it's completely useless.

Also, when there is some timeout set that fires before you manage to create your event (e.g. mouse click), the break will occur on that timeout.